# How to validate entires in arrays in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have made a schema `Loc` which has a property `places` which is an array of strings. I want to validate the elements of the arrays. Elements must not be empty strings, or strings containing only spaces. I only want non-empty non whitespace strings. I am using the match validator for the purpose.

So I've tried the following code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const arrSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    value: { type: String, match: /^(?!\s*$).+/ }
})

const Loc = mongoose.model('Loc', {
    num: Number,
    places: [arrSchema]
});

(async ()=>{
    try{
        await mongoose.connect.....

        let data1 = new Loc({
            num: 1,
            places: ['a','b','c']
        });

        // this one should work
        console.log('trying save one');
        await data1.save();
        console.log("data1 saved");

        let data2 = new Loc({
            num: 2,
            places: [' ','p','q']
        });

        // this one should not
        console.log('trying save two');
        await data2.save();
        console.log('data2 saved');

        process.exit(0);

    } catch(err){
        console.log("Error");
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();
```

But the code throws validation error while trying to save `data1`.
Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are two ways you can do that**

**First:** you have created schema which will take an **object {"value": "string"}** in **places Array** and in code, you are directly passing string in the array that's why it is not working.

Below is the updated code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const arrSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    value: { type: String, match: /^(?!\s*$).+/ }
})

const Loc = mongoose.model('Loc', {
    num: Number,
    places: [arrSchema]
});

(async ()=>{
    try{
        await mongoose.connect.....

        let data1 = new Loc({
            num: 1,
            places: [{"value": "a"},{"value": "b"},{"value": "c"}]
        });

        // this one should work
        console.log('trying save one');
        await data1.save();
        console.log("data1 saved");

        let data2 = new Loc({
            num: 2,
            places: [{"value": " "},{"value": "p"},{"value": "q"}]
        });

        // this one should not
        console.log('trying save two');
        await data2.save();
        console.log('data2 saved');

        process.exit(0);

    } catch(err){
        console.log("Error");
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();
```

**Second:** if you don't want objects in the **places Array** You should update your Loc Schema and put a custom validator like shown in below code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var LocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  num: Number,
  places: {
    type: [String],
    validate: {
      validator: function(value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (!(/^(?!\s*$).+/.test(value[i]))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
       return true;
      },
      message: props => `Location should not be empty`
    }
  }
});
const Loc = mongoose.model('Loc', LocSchema);

(async ()=>{
    try{
        await mongoose.connect.....

        let data1 = new Loc({
            num: 1,
            places: ['a','b','c']
        });

        // this one should work
        console.log('trying save one');
        await data1.save();
        console.log("data1 saved");

        let data2 = new Loc({
            num: 2,
            places: [' ','p','q']
        });
    // this one should not
    console.log('trying save two');
    await data2.save();
    console.log('data2 saved');

    process.exit(0);

} catch(err){
    console.log("Error");
    process.exit(1);
}
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! The second one suits my purpose.

Comment: Happy to help :)